# Spoilers in linked/related sidebar

Tags: feature-request, spoilers

[Here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/74803) is a situation where I avoid linking one of my questions to one of my answers, and the reason I give is:

> But please do not link it, because then when someone looks at the puzzle, "Unsolved maths problems as puzzles" would show up in that pesky 'linked'/'related' sidebar ... which would be sort of a spoiler!

That's annoying. But at least there's a workaround -- don't link directly!

A worse situation is [this puzzle of mine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72982). At the time of writing, when I click on it, the first entry in the 'related' sidebar is

> Hidden in plain sight - By what method do these images hide a prime number?

Which is a massive hint. CURSE YOU, STACKEXCHANGE ALGORITHM!

Is there any trick we can use to avoid this situation?

The answer is probably "no, too bad." The reason I'm asking is in order to disguise my complaint as a question. And hey, technically, it is a real question, because I don't actually know how the 'related' sidebar works. It's unlikely, but not totally impossible, that there's already a way to avoid this, via some arcane markup or something. It's also unlikely, but not impossible, that a developer will take pity on me.

Comment: Related (heh): [How are "related" questions selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20473/how-are-related-questions-selected)

Comment: "Questions" on meta don't have to be questions; it's perfectly fine for a [[tag:feature-request]] to just be an argument for that feature.

Comment: *"because then when someone looks at the puzzle, "Unsolved maths problems as puzzles" would show up in that pesky 'linked'/'related' sidebar ..."* You mean *Linked* sidebar, not *Related*, right?

Comment: Right .. but we hates them both, nasssty spoiling sidebarses

Comment: About the possibility of a developer noticing this - I'm pretty sure they don't check per-site metas at all, unless something gets the [status-review] tag (which is only supposed to be applied in cases of clear community consensus and need)